# Multiply column values and display them

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a query of an orders table to find an order number based on a user given id and then give a total for the order based on the quantity * price. I have the following

```
 @ordertotals = Orderlines.where(id: @orderinfo.id).sum("quantity * price")
```

which would place the total in to a new object for each one. I am then trying to display all of the values found to do that I have

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Order Number</td>
    <td>Order Date</td>
    <td>Cost of Order</td>
  </tr>
    <% # for each customer who has this sales rep
  # display each customer in a row
  for @custdata in @orderinfo   %>
              <tr>
                    <td><%=@orderinfo.id%></td>
                    <td><%=@orderinfo.order_date%></td>
            <% for @orderinfo in @ordertotals %>
                    <td><%=@ordertotals%></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Which would loop through the @orderinfo first to display the id and order date then loop through the @ordertotals to display each total. However when I run this I get compiler errors on the

```
@ordertotals = Orderlines.where(id: @orderinfo.id).sum("quantity * price")
```

line, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here and if the way I have printing setup would work?

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add the errors here they are

```
compile error
/rails1/app/views/ordersdisplay.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...rtotals = Orderlines.where(id: @orderinfo.id).sum("quantity ...
                          ^
/rails1/app/views/ordersdisplay.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting   kEND
...lines.where(id: @orderinfo.id).sum("quantity * price")
                          ^
/rails1/app/views/ordersdisplay.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also what is the output of `Orderlines.where(id: @orderinfo.id)`

Comment: Sorry just added them in

Comment: Depending on what version of ruby you're running, you may need to change that `where` to `where(:id => @orderinfo.id)`

Comment: It is actually telling me that where is not defined. `undefined method where' for #<Class:0x7f8447464998>`

Comment: I don't think you can make queries from the erb view templates like that ... maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't that logic be in the controller?

Comment: I know you can use .find in the erb because I have them working in another part of this, but you could be correct that you cannot do .where queries in erb. I am a total noob at ruby on rails though...